# How to change the column type of a pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to Python but quite expierenced with R.

I'm trying to convert a column type of an unstructured Excel file read in with pandas. The column that I want to convert to a number contains both the format time and string.

[image]

I want to add a column `hours` that states in this example `8` (18:00:00 - 10:00:00).
In R this is quite simple with `dplyr` and `as.numeric`. `As.numeric` converts `18:00:00` to `18` and `Z` to `0`.

I'm a stuck with the problem that pandas uses objects instead of a single type for a column.
Could someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert times to timedeltas, then subtract columns, convert to seconds and and divide by `3600` for hours:

```
df['ma_start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['ma_start'].astype(str), errors='coerce')
df['ma_end'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['ma_end'].astype(str), errors='coerce')
df['diff'] = df['ma_end'].sub(df['ma_start']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
```